# Can something like this be done with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wonder, can something like this small Flash interactive presentation be done with jQuery (with all these effects like easing, popups, slide-ins, etc)? 
Example here:
http://www.manh.com/platforms/manhattan-scope 
(click on "Manhattan SCOPE" on the right hand side)
I want to re-do a similar Flash presentation in jQuery (or something else mobile-friendly). I know jQuery but not sure what exactly I need to pull something like this together. Can anyone point me to the resources that explain how to build a similar Flash-like presentation? What jQuery plugins would I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flash in question features the following effects:

1. Animated resizing.
2. Animated fade in/fade out.
3. Animate font size.
4. An animated graphic (the spinning circle around the logo on the right).

1, 2, and 3 are all things that can be accomplished using the [built-in Effects methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) in jQuery (`.slideUp`/`.slideDown`/`.slideToggle`, `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut`/`.fadeToggle`, and `.animate`, respectively).

Your first step is to read the docs thoroughly for Effects and understand how they work.

4, on the other hand, would be tricky. Your best bet would probably be to use a static GIF, and animated GIF, replacing the static with the animated on mouseover, and vise versa.

However, all being said, yes, I think that example is well within the capabilities of jQuery.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such detailed answer! I'll give it a try. Thank you!